# StackOverflow-error when applying pyspark ALS's "recommendProductsForUsers" (although cluster of >300GB Ram available)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, recommendation-engine, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-platform

Looking for expertise to guide me on issue below.

**Background:**

- I'm trying to get going with a basic PySpark script inspired on [this
  example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-recommendation-engine/blob/master/pyspark/app_collaborative.py)
- As deploy infrastructure I use a Google Cloud Dataproc Cluster.
- Cornerstone in my code is the function  "recommendProductsForUsers" documented [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/recommendation/MatrixFactorizationModel.html#recommendProductsForUsers(int)) which gives me back the top X products for all users in the model

**Issue I incur**

- The ALS.Train script runs smoothly and scales well on GCP (Easily >1mn customers).
- However,  applying the predictions: i.e. using funcitons 'PredictAll' or 'recommendProductsForUsers', does not scale at all. My script runs smooth for a small dataset (<100 Customer
  with <100 products). However, when bringing it to a business-relevant size, I don't manage to scale it (e.g., >50k Customers and >10k products)
- Error I then get is below:

  ```
   16/08/16 14:38:56 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager:
     Lost task 22.0 in stage 411.0 (TID 15139,
     productrecommendation-high-w-2.c.main-nova-558.internal):
     java.lang.StackOverflowError
          at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
          at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
          at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
          at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
          at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
          at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
          at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
          at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
          at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
          at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
          at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
          at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
          at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
          at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
          at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
          at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
          at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
          at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
          at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
          at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
  ```
- I even went as far as getting a 300 GB Cluster (1 main node of 108GB + 2 nodes of 108 GB RAM) to try it to run it; it works for 50k customers but not for anything more
- Ambition is to have a setup where I can run for >800k customers

**Details**

Code line where it fails

```
predictions = model.recommendProductsForUsers(10).flatMap(lambda p: p[1]).map(lambda p: (str(p[0]), str(p[1]), float(p[2])))
pprint.pprint(predictions.take(10))
schema = StructType([StructField("customer", StringType(), True), StructField("sku", StringType(), True), StructField("prediction", FloatType(), True)])
dfToSave = sqlContext.createDataFrame(predictions, schema).dropDuplicates()
```

How do you suggest to proceed? I feel that the 'merging' part at the end of my script (i.e. when I write it to dfToSave) causes the error; is there a way to bypass this & save part-by-part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the stack trace this appears to be the same issue as [Spark gives a StackOverflowError when training using ALS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484460/spark-gives-a-stackoverflowerror-when-training-using-als)

Basically, Spark expresses RDD lineage recursively so that you end up with deeply nested objects when things haven't been lazy evaluated over the course of an iterative workload. Calling sc.setCheckpointDir and adjusting the checkpoint interval will mitigate the length of this RDD lineage.

Comment: Hi Dennis, thanks for your thoughts. I saw indeed that other thread & I agree that the ALS.train indeed has a checkpoint interval parameter which you can custom. However, the predictAll nor the recommendProductsForUsers-function has this parameter; how would the checkpoint-ing then work?

Comment: Update: Implemented Checkpointing (Thanks dennis for the tip). Although it allows for very good scaling of the ALS.train function (easily >1mn customers), it doesn't work for applying the predicitions: i;e. using the funcitons PredictAll or recommendProductsForUsers. Any suggestion for this?

Comment: After applying the checkpointing, do you still see the same stack trace involving the `ObjectInputStream` when an exception gets thrown, or has it changed?

Comment: Hi Dennis; in essence: no errors anymore but the part where we apply the predicitions (i;e. using the funcitons PredictAll or recommendProductsForUsers) is very slow vs. the rest of the code (takes 2hours while the ALS.train only takes 2mins).
Any recommendations to speed up? I moved to 1master+30 small workes now which during this step seem not challenged on CPU nor ram. wdyt?

Comment: @BartV, the reason it happens, is when you do 'predict' or 'recommend' you need to create a cross between your users and your products. Basically, for each of your users, you need to predict each product, and find the top scoring ones.
How many executors are you running? In my first attempts, I found out I was using the default (3...), when I increased to 50 (which meant the prediction had to handle 50^2=2500 tasks!) I saw a significant improvement in performance.