# Spark ML ALS collaborative filtering always fail if the iteration more than 20

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

My data set‘s size is about 3G and has 380 million datas. Always wrong if I add iteration steps. And increase memory, increase block or decrease block, decrease checkpoint cannot solve my problem.

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

The method introduced to set small checkpoint cannot solve my problem.
[StackOverflow-error when applying pyspark ALS's "recommendProductsForUsers" (although cluster of >300GB Ram available)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979654/stackoverflow-error-when-applying-pyspark-alss-recommendproductsforusers-alt)

This is the DataFrame for ALS training, which is about 380 million rows.

```
+---------+-----------+------+
| user_id|item_id|rating|
+---------+-----------+------+
|154317644|      58866|     6|
| 69669214|     601866|     7|
|126094876|     909352|     3|
| 45246613|    1484481|     3|
|123317968|    2101977|     3|
|   375928|    2681933|     1|
|136939309|    3375806|     2|
|  3150751|    4198976|     2|
| 87648646|    1030196|     3|
| 57672425|    5385142|     2|
+---------+-----------+------+
```

This is the code to train ALS.

```
val als = new ALS()
  .setMaxIter(setMaxIter)
  .setRegParam(setRegParam)
  .setUserCol("user_id")
  .setItemCol("item_id")
  .setRatingCol("rating")
  .setImplicitPrefs(false)
  .setCheckpointInterval(setCheckpointInterval)
  .setRank(setRank)
  .setNumItemBlocks(setNumItemBlocks)
  .setNumUserBlocks(setNumUserBlocks)

val Array(training, test) = ratings.randomSplit(Array(0.9, 0.1))
val model = als.fit(training)   // wrong in this step
```

This is the ALS source code where error happens.

```
val srcOut = srcOutBlocks.join(srcFactorBlocks).flatMap {
  case (srcBlockId, (srcOutBlock, srcFactors)) =>
    srcOutBlock.view.zipWithIndex.map { case (activeIndices, dstBlockId) =>
      (dstBlockId, (srcBlockId, activeIndices.map(idx => srcFactors(idx))))
    }
}
```

This is the Exception and Error logs.

```
    18/08/23 15:05:43 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
18/08/23 15:13:35 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 20.0 in stage 56.0 (TID 31322, 6.ai.bjs-datalake.p1staff.com, executor 9): java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:3170)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHandle(ObjectInputStream.java:1678)

18/08/23 15:13:35 WARN server.TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /10.191.161.108:23300
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)

18/08/23 15:13:36 ERROR cluster.YarnClusterScheduler: Lost executor 15 on 2.ai.bjs-datalake.p1staff.com: Container marked as failed: container_e04_1533096025492_4001_01_000016 on host: 2.ai.bjs-datalake.p1staff.com. Exit status: 50. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e04_1533096025492_4001_01_000016
Exit code: 50
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=50: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:482)


18/08/23 15:05:43 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
18/08/23 15:13:35 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 20.0 in stage 56.0 (TID 31322, 6.ai.bjs-datalake.p1staff.com, executor 9): java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2669)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:3170)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHandle(ObjectInputStream.java:1678)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1739)

18/08/23 15:13:36 ERROR cluster.YarnClusterScheduler: Lost executor 10 on 5.ai.bjs-datalake.p1staff.com: Container marked as failed: container_e04_1533096025492_4001_01_000011 on host: 5.ai.bjs-datalake.p1staff.com. Exit status: 50. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e04_1533096025492_4001_01_000011
Exit code: 50
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=50: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:776)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Is anybody meet this error?

Comment: Can you provide an MVCE please ? With the current description I can only refer to the solution given in answer you've linked to solve your problem.

Comment: @eliasah, do you need to know any other information please?

Comment: This is not what I have asked for. I suggest that you read the following and update your question according to the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples

Comment: @eliasah FYI, please.

Comment: Have you set the checkpoint directory in your spark context configuration ?

Comment: Yes, I tried 100, 10, 4, 2, 1. But they all do not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178595/discussion-between-eliasah-and-gary-yong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After set the check point directory, it works. Thank @eliasah

`spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("hdfs://datalake/check_point_directory/als")`

Check point will not work if you do not set the directory.

Comment: You can accept your answer.