# Spark Scala Checkpointing Data Set showing .isCheckpointed = false after Action but directories written

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, checkpointing

There seem to be a few postings on this but none seem to answer what I understand.

The following code run on DataBricks:

```scala
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("/dbfs/FileStore/checkpoint/cp1/loc7")
val checkpointDir = spark.sparkContext.getCheckpointDir.get
val ds = spark.range(10).repartition(2)
ds.cache()
ds.checkpoint()
ds.count()
ds.rdd.isCheckpointed
```

Added an improvement of sorts:

```scala
...
val ds2 = ds.checkpoint(eager=true)
println(ds2.queryExecution.toRdd.toDebugString)
...
```

returns:

```
(2) MapPartitionsRDD[307] at toRdd at command-1835760423149753:13 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[305] at checkpoint at command-1835760423149753:12 []
 |  ReliableCheckpointRDD[306] at checkpoint at command-1835760423149753:12 []
 checkpointDir: String = dbfs:/dbfs/FileStore/checkpoint/cp1/loc10/86cc77b5-27c3-4049-9136-503ddcab0fa9
 ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]
 ds2: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]
 res53: Boolean = false
```

**Question 1:**

**ds.rdd.isCheckpointed** or **ds2.rdd.isCheckpointed** both return **False** even though with count I have a non-lazy situation. Why, when in particular the ../loc 7 & 10 are written with (part) files? Also we can see that ReliableCheckPoint!

Not well explained the whole concept. Trying to sort this out.

**Question 2** - secondary question:

Is the cache really necessary or not with latest versions of Spark 2.4? A new branch on the ds, if not cached, will it cause re-computation or is that better now? Seems odd the checkpoint data would not be used, or could we say Spark does not really know what is better?

From High Performance Spark I get the mixed impression that check pointing is not so recommended, but then again it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyspark rdd isCheckPointed() is false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336256/pyspark-rdd-ischeckpointed-is-false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: You don't inspect the object that is actually checkpointed:

```scala
ds2.queryExecution.toRdd.dependencies(0).rdd.isCheckpointed
// Boolean = true
```

> ds.rdd.isCheckpointed or ds2.rdd.isCheckpointed both return False

That is an expected behavior. The object being checkpointed is not the converted RDD (which is a result of the additional transformations required to convert to external representation), that you reference, but the internal RDD object (in fact, as you see above, it is not even the latest internal RDD, but its parent).

Additionally, in the first case you just use a wrong `Dataset` object whatsoever - as explained in the  [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336256/pyspark-rdd-ischeckpointed-is-false) `Dataset.checkpoint` [returns a new `Dataset`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/075447b3965489ffba4e6afb2b120880bc307505/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L640-L648)

> even though with count I have a non-lazy situation

That doesn't make much sense. The default `checkpoint` implementation [is `eager`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/075447b3965489ffba4e6afb2b120880bc307505/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L562), therefore it [force evaluates](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/075447b3965489ffba4e6afb2b120880bc307505/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L623). Even if it wasn't for that, [`Dataset.count` is not the right way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50379782/10465355) to force evaluation.

> Is the cache really necessary or not with latest version

As you can see in the linked source, `Dataset.checkpoint` uses `RDD.checkpoint` internally so the same rule apply. However you already execute a separate action to force checkpoint, so additional caching, especially considering the cost of `Dataset` persistence, could be an overkill.

Of course, if in doubt, you might consider benchmarking in a specific context.